# Symfony 4.4.18 debug toolbar not showing in local docker host

Tags: php, docker, symfony, symfony4, xdebug

I have created a full symfony project (composer create-project composer create-project symfony / website-skeleton myproj "^ 4.4.18").

After having configured the environment variables (trusted_host, database_url, etc ...).

1. If I run php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public /
   => Everything works perfectly. I have the symfony welcome page with the debug toolbar
   [image]
2. On the other hand, if I access it from a host in my local docker workspace (I use nginx): everything appears fine like the other EXCEPT the debug toolbar
   [image]

I have this error in my console. I don't know if it concerns

[image]

***While for the docker environment, the php is in version 7.4.14 and with an xdebug v3.0.1 installed and activated.***

and I even made sure that /var/cache/ was in chmod -R 777.

could someone help me display this debug toolbar?

Comment: Your browsers console should contain a failed request to fetch the toolbar, what errors are you getting for it?

Comment: Both the PHP server and NGINX are pointing at the exact same codebase? Same .env file, composer.json, etc?

Comment: @Chase i get **(index):116 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://i-ray.kaiza.lh/' was loaded over HTTPS** in my browser console

Comment: @Alex.Barylski I think so. Otherwise, it wouldn't be able to display the home page in debug mode, right?

Comment: I was stupid. it was the nginx config. I just put **fastcgi_param HTTPS on;** and it worked as I made sure to work in https. Anyway thank you guys